# How can I download cmisfile

Tags: liferay, alfresco, cmis

I have problem with downloading a pdf file from a particular link.
For example I have a URL like `http://<host>:<port>/alfresco/service/content.pdf`
and in Liferay I want to download a file from this link.

I tried this:

```
resourceResponse.setContentType("application/pdf");
resourceResponse.addProperty(HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL, "max-age=3600, must-revalidate");
resourceResponse.addProperty(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,"filename=" + url); 
OutputStream out = resourceResponse.getPortletOutputStream();
```

Comment: Do you want to download this file from Liferay or redirect the browser to the Alfresco URL?

Comment: want to download file

Comment: Need (*a lot*) more details: e.g. Are you using Liferay's CMIS-Store for document library? (it seems not). Or do you have an external Alfresco that you want to proxy the alfresco files through Liferay? Are the files public or do you need the user's identity to access the files in Alfresco? What's the setup that you're running - how do you get at the URL you mention: Is this a standalone Alfresco URL or is it a Liferay URL? Why can't you just point to the standalone Alfresco URL if it is one? etc etc

Comment: yes, I integrate my liferay with alfreso using cmis repository.. I upload all my files in alfresco repository. In searching facility i want to download file from particular url. I get all my file url based on my searching criteria from alfresco repository using opencmis api. Now I just want to download my file from that url. At liferay site i am using liferay-ui:search-container